# xtermjs fit addon causes line to overwrite previous line

Tags: xtermjs

The fit addon causes a line in xtermjs to overwrite previous lines. Specifically, when the user types, half a line is filled up, and then the characters begin appearing from the left hand side of the line and overwriting the previous characters written there.

```js
const fitAddon = new FitAddon.FitAddon()
term.loadAddon(fitAddon)
fitAddon.fit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the columns of xterm and columns of your serverside PTY are not equivalent. You can change the xterm columns and rows like this.

```
const term = new Terminal({
  rows: x,
  cols: y,
});
```

Where x and y are your PTY rows and columns.